# AWS - Direct Connect to Direct Connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-direct-connect

Is it possible to create a point to point Direct Connect between AWS regions?

If I create a Direct Connection with the same Service Provider for:

- (ap-northeast-1) in Equinix TY2, TY6 - TY8, Tokyo
- (eu-west-2) in Telehouse West, London, GBR

Am I able to use these two ports on EC2 instances located in ap-northeast-1 and eu-west-2 to communicate directly?

If it is possible could you provide step by step instructions for setting this up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a [Direct Connect Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-direct-connect-gateway-inter-region-vpc-access/) if you're wanting to connect to multiple regions to your on premise.

If you simply want to connect the 2 VPCs together with no need to connect to on premise then use a [VPC Peer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/create-vpc-peering-connection.html) between your VPCs. This will use AWS backbone network to connect and transfer data between the 2 VPCs without any internet bound transit.

Comment: I want to use a service provider that shows to have low latency between tokyo and london (around 170ms) compared to the AWS backbone which is 220ms. Thats why I want to use Direct Connect

Comment: Hi, its probably going to be very close in actual speed and costly to have Direct Connect for this problem. I'd suggest contacting AWS support and talking through your current setup.

Comment: so this setup is possible? I would like to test the actual latency myself. I understand the cost involved, but if the latency is under 200ms its worth it for my use case. If you could outline the basic steps, I will accept your answer.

Comment: Hi, this would not be possible. Direct Connect requires the configuration of an on-premise router. AWS uses a managed router per subnet. I’d really suggest contacting AWS support